# Extract ramdon values ​in database with more than 8M records in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Have a table in my database with around 9,000,000 data.

My problem occurs at the time of

and consult that table through Laravel, since when doing only the query to extract all the data with `Number::all();` Well, my server obviously collapses because of its capacity, but my detail is that I need to extract around 50,000 data randomly from that table and I don't know how to do it. Since the Random method of the Collection does not execute it since the server falling does not generate anything for me.

What could you propose to be able to generate my query? How could I do it? It's a matter of my company and I really don't know what else to do.

This is the error that always generates me when consulting:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted

When testing with `chunk` it generates values ​​in less than 2 seconds, the detail is that it brings me the values ​​starting with the first index of the table when random values ​​are needed.

I did the test with this code

```
$numeros = Number::select('NUMBERS_ID', 'NUMBER')
             ->inRandomOrder()
             ->take(1000)
             ->get()
             ->chunk(100);
```

But it still generates an amount of time of about 2 minutes

I need to generate random data in a considered amount of time of about 30 seconds, but I am receiving random responses with an approximate 2 minutes.

Comment: orms bork on big data, your need to look into doing a manual query, most likly inRandomOrder prob resolves to a `ORDER BY RAND` which is slow as

Comment: sidenote: 2097152 is around 2mb, thats not alot to work with, you should increase it abit

Comment: How much can be recommended for use in this case? Checking my php.ini the value in memory_limit = 1024MB, but I am talking about the xampp php.ini I don't know if the Laravel server has its own php.ini but in another path

Comment: something is setting it to `2M`, do a phpinfo() to find out which php.ini is loaded.. 2mb is really not enough when working with lots of data which is filling up them orm objects, collections and fluff.